# ReactJS - getting base64 string out of Barcode image component

Tags: reactjs, barcode

I would think this should be a pretty easy thing to do.  I can render a Barcode onto the page and it shows up correctly and if I copy image location on it, it is a full base64 string.  You can see that working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hawking-ow9mk

Now all I want to do is get that base64 string into my code.
Here is what I have tried:

```
const encodeSvg = reactElement => {
    return (
        'data:image/png;base64,' +
        escape(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(reactElement))
    );
};

const barcode = encodeSvg(
    <Barcode value={'72527273070'} renderer={'img'} />
);

console.log(barcode);
```

All the console log spits out is: `data:image/png;base64,%3Cimg/%3E` or if I remove the escape: `data:image/png;base64,<img/>`.  So it's like I need to somehow grab the src property of the image or something.

Comment: The sandbox link isn't showing anything. Just a default react setup

Comment: Woops, I don't think I saved it, try again.

Comment: It's there. So, you are trying to get the actual string for the image to be usable in your App component? Stored in a variable perhaps?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I've updated the sandbox code with some of my tries.

Comment: I was working with the sandbox you provided and it seems that, until you render Barcode component, src does not gets associated with the img tag and so you do not get the output. As Brian pointed out you either render it on server side or you can render on client side (make it hidden if needed) and then you will get the result

Comment: I am facing the same problem, were you able to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the only `<img>` tag on the page, you should be able to grab the contents with:

`document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].currentSrc` or 
`document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].outerHTML` if you want the element itself.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Comment: That's the thing.  I'm pretty sure it's not even on the page at this point.  In fact I need to get that string before the page is rendered in order to feed it into another component.

Comment: So you need to render the barcode server-side and save the resulting info into a variable that you can pass into your App. I'm not all that familiar with React SSR other than you need to use 'hydrate' instead of 'render' and you need a second environment other than your client. The jsbarcode library should be none-the-wiser, though.